# Rails routing, :as option also changes the params hash ... how to override that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have a hairy set of routes that I'm upgrading from Rails 2 to Rails 3.  In Rails 2, the routes file was written like so:

```
map.resources :stories, :path_prefix => ':user_id', :name_prefix => 'user_', :controller => :user_stories, :do |story|
  story.resources :article_clips
end
```

And that produced this set of routes:

```
          user_story_article_clips GET    /:user_id/stories/:story_id/article_clips(.:format)                  {:controller=>"article_clips", :action=>"index"}
                                   POST   /:user_id/stories/:story_id/article_clips(.:format)                  {:controller=>"article_clips", :action=>"create"}
       new_user_story_article_clip GET    /:user_id/stories/:story_id/article_clips/new(.:format)              {:controller=>"article_clips", :action=>"new"}
      edit_user_story_article_clip GET    /:user_id/stories/:story_id/article_clips/:id/edit(.:format)         {:controller=>"article_clips", :action=>"edit"}
           user_story_article_clip GET    /:user_id/stories/:story_id/article_clips/:id(.:format)              {:controller=>"article_clips", :action=>"show"}
                                   PUT    /:user_id/stories/:story_id/article_clips/:id(.:format)              {:controller=>"article_clips", :action=>"update"}
                                   DELETE /:user_id/stories/:story_id/article_clips/:id(.:format)              {:controller=>"article_clips", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Note how the URL example contains ':story_id' -- that is, the name_prefix has not influenced the name of the 'story_id' in the params hash (ie, you'll be able to get at it via 'params[:story_id]' ...

So I have managed to translate this with some success, this is what I have so far:

```
scope ":user_id" do
  resources :stories, :as => 'user_story', :controller => :user_stories do
    resources :article_clips
  end
end
```

It's all good, except by using ':as', note how the object that getting put into the params hash has been renamed to ':user_story_id':

```
          user_story_article_clips GET    /:user_id/stories/:user_story_id/article_clips(.:format)             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"article_clips"}
                                   POST   /:user_id/stories/:user_story_id/article_clips(.:format)             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"article_clips"}
       new_user_story_article_clip GET    /:user_id/stories/:user_story_id/article_clips/new(.:format)         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"article_clips"}
      edit_user_story_article_clip GET    /:user_id/stories/:user_story_id/article_clips/:id/edit(.:format)    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"article_clips"}
           user_story_article_clip GET    /:user_id/stories/:user_story_id/article_clips/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"article_clips"}
                                   PUT    /:user_id/stories/:user_story_id/article_clips/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"article_clips"}
                                   DELETE /:user_id/stories/:user_story_id/article_clips/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"article_clips"}
```

I've tried many different things, ':name_prefix' doesn't work at all, that ':path_prefix' thing also doesn't work anymore.  How can I accomplish this?  Am I going to have to write out these routes by hand with 'match' statements?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing the routes out by hand, like so:

```
match '/:user_id/stories/:story_id/article_clips(.:format)'           => 'article_clips#index',   :via => :get, :as => :user_story_article_clips
match '/:user_id/stories/:story_id/article_clips(.:format)'           => 'article_clips#create',  :via => :post
match '/:user_id/stories/:story_id/article_clips/new(.:format)'       => 'article_clips#new',     :via => :get, :as => :new_user_story_article_clip
match '/:user_id/stories/:story_id/article_clips/:id/edit(.:format)'  => 'article_clips#edit',    :via => :get, :as => :edit_user_story_article_clip
match '/:user_id/stories/:story_id/article_clips/:id(.:format)'       => 'article_clips#show',    :via => :get, :as => :user_story_article_clip
match '/:user_id/stories/:story_id/article_clips/:id(.:format)'       => 'article_clips#update',  :via => :put
match '/:user_id/stories/:story_id/article_clips/:id(.:format)'       => 'article_clips#destroy', :via => :delete
```

It's unpleasant but it worked for my needs.  The view helpers with the 'user_' name_prefix are used throughout the app (I grep 84 places), so I need to preserve that.  But with the ':user_story' param -- it breaks the route, the 'story' cannot be found.

Sorry if my explanation of the problem is not very legible.  If anyone knows a terser solution (if the 'name_prefix' option were working in Rails 3 as it does in Rails 2, I think that would be the way to do it ...) -- for example, this used to work, but doesn't now:

```
scope ":user_id" do
  resources :stories, :name_prefix => 'user_', :controller => :user_stories do
    resources :article_clips
  end
end
```